# Reordering rows of mysql table fetched dynamically using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page in my web project which displays a complete table fetched from MySQL database. I want to add a option or an extra column on the HTML table that will help to move rows up and down, wherever I want to put it. Like, moving row 1 to row 10, row 2 to row 5, etc. and dynamically making changes in the MySQL table. And also how will I be able to do it on the HTML page by providing some arrows or drag and drop or what ?

Comment: So you want to have a `position` type column used for sorting?

Comment: You might be interested in searching about jQuery draggable for the ui and perhaps using Ajax to update.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or tutorial or library finding service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: @tadman : yes exactly, and when I change it using arrows or something on my HTML page, those changes should reflect in the database mysql table, because further that table is used to generate dynamic csv files

Comment: @JeffPuckettII: okay .... both the technologies you mentioned are new for me, I will have to search on it

Comment: This is going to require a bunch of things to come together and mesh up properly, so try and break it down into smaller problems. As some have said, you'll need an AJAX component as well. Saving the resulting order will require a sorting column like `position`. You really don't have enough here to build off of, so I'd recommend trying to tackle it in smaller chunks, especially when it comes to Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: @tadman : okay, I will start working on this things, as I am unsure about it right now, may be will try to use jquery draggable and AJAX for updating the table. Thanks